# Validate a column to accept only certain age limit from birthdate given using check constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, check-constraints

A business rule required my table to only registrater  certain dob from bithDate column to be inserted or allow. I created the check constraint but i kind of having logical error i not able to spot out. pls advise

```
ALTER TABLE Personalinfo
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_ValidDOB   CHECK  
(
CASE
    WHEN (convert(int,DATEDIFF(M, BirthDate, getdate())/12) BETWEEN 30 AND 33) THEN 1
    ELSE BirthDate
END = 1
);
Error message:  `Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_ValidDOB"`
```

Comment: Does the table already contains data ? If yes , one of the existing record might conflict with the new constraint that tries to be put in place.  Another possibility is that the format of the column chk_validDOB does not accept one of the two types of values you're trying to input: either a birthdate or the number 1 ?

Comment: @JoBedard, Yes, i just deleted the records and ran the it. work run sucessfully

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the issue is that the `ELSE` is returning `BirthDate` instead of `0`.

If there is already data in the table that conflicts, then add the `WITH NOCHECK` clause if you want to keep that data, else first delete any rows that conflict with the new constraint.

Also, best to use `MONTH` instead of `M` for the date part, for easier readability.